# How to use precompiled headers with a qmake extra compiler?

Tags: qmake

When using the default qmake compiler (via the `SOURCES` variable), I can use precompiled headers like so:

```
CONFIG += precompile_header
PRECOMPILED_HEADER = stable.h
SOURCES = main.c
```

However, I'd like to use a custom compiler (via `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS`).  I tried this:

```
CONFIG += precompile_header
PRECOMPILED_HEADER = stable.h
MY_SOURCES = main.c

my.input = MY_SOURCES
my.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}.o
my.commands = clang $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_USE_PRECOMPILE -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += my
```

...and the precompiled headers are built, but my custom compiler fails because `QMAKE_CFLAGS_USE_PRECOMPILE` doesn't contain the path to the precompiled header.  (It is defined as `-Xclang -include-pch -Xclang ${QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT}`, and apparently `${QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT}` is empty.)

How can I get the name of the generated precompiled header, so I can pass it as a parameter to my custom compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the qmake source code, precompiled header handling seems to be hardcoded in `UnixMakefileGenerator::init()` to only work for the built-in C, CXX, OBJC, and OBJCXX compilers.

`QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT`, for GCC and Clang-style precompiled headers, is constructed by combining `PRECOMPILED_DIR`, `TARGET`, one of `c`/`c++`/`objective-c`/`objective-c++`, and `QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT_EXT`.  So, in the question's second example, the following command line should work:

```
my.commands = clang -Xclang -include-pch -Xclang $$TARGET/c$$QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT_EXT -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
```